# JOOQ initializing DAO Best Approach

Tags: java, sql, jooq, vert.x

I want to know Best practices for initilizing JOOQ generated DAO. Now,I am using following approach for initilization of JOOQ generated DAO. In following case StudentDao  is JOOQ generated.

```
public class ExtendedStudentDAO extends StudentDao {
    public ExtendedStudentDAO () {
        super();
    }

    public ExtendedStudentDAO (Connection connection) {
        Configuration configuration = DSL.using(connection,
                JDBCUtils.dialect(connection)).configuration();

        this.setConfiguration(configuration);
    }

    //adding extra methods to DAO using DSL
    public String getStudentName(Long ID)
            throws SQLException {

        try (Connection connection = ServiceConnectionManager.getConnection()) {

            DSLContext dslContext = ServiceConnectionManager
                    .getDSLContext(connection);

            Record1<String> record = dslContext
                    .select(Student.Name)
                    .from(Student.Student)
                    .where(Student.ID
                            .equal(ID)).fetchOne();

            if (record != null) {
                return record.getValue(Student.Name);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have doubt with using above DAO my example code is below.

```
try (Connection connection = ServiceConnectionManager.getConnection()) {

ExtendedStudentDAO extendedStudentDAO =new ExtendedStudentDAO(connection);

Student stud=new Student();
.....
....

//insert method is from Generated DAO
extendedStudentDAO.insert(stud); 

//this method is added in extended class
extendedStudentDAO.getStudentName(12);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this kind of initialisation:

#### Create DAOs every time you need them

Your approach is correct, but might be considered a bit heavy. You're creating a new `DAO` every time you need it.

As of jOOQ 3.7, a `DAO` is a pretty lightweight object. The same is true for the `Configuration` that wraps your `Connection`.

Once your project evolves (or in future jOOQ versions), that might no longer be true, as your `Configuration` initialisation (or jOOQ's `DAO` initialisation) might become heavier.

But this is a small risk, and it would be easy to fix:

#### Use dependency injection to manage `DAO` or `Configuration` references

Most people will set up only a single jOOQ `Configuration` for their application, and also only a single `DAO` instance (per `DAO` type), somewhere in a service. In this case, your `Configuration` must not share the `Connection` reference, but provide a `Connection` to jOOQ via the [`ConnectionProvider` SPI](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html). In your case, that seems trivial enough:

```
class MyConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {
    @Override
    public Connection acquire() {
         return ServiceConnectionManager.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Connection connection) {
         try {
             connection.close();
         }
         catch (SQLException e) {
             throw new DataAccessException("Error while closing", e);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you're planning to use DAOs inside a transaction? Should you instantiate the DAO with the scoped configuration for the transaction? Or does it not matter

Comment: @NayeemZen If you're using jOOQ's transaction API, then yes you'll have to instantiate the DAO with the scoped configuration. If you're using Spring's transaction API (which is thread-bound), then you don't need to instantiate separate DAOs. In case of doubt, feel free to ask a new question and I'll explain.