# Use jOOQ with Play Framework

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework-2.0, jooq

I'm trying to create a base project with Play Framework 2.5 and jOOQ 3.9 using PostgreSQL 9.5 as database. This project is structured in three main layers: *controllers*, *services* and *daos* (and I only have one instance of every service and dao due to Guice dependency injection).

To work with jOOQ transactions over controller's methods I have developed the following Java Action:

```
public class DatabaseTransactionAction extends Action.Simple {

  @Inject
  private Database database;

  private Connection connection;    

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<Result> call (Http.Context ctx) {

    connection = database.getDataSource().getConnection();

    // Make JOOQ work with the connection acquired
    DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using (connection,
                                       SQLDialect.POSTGRES, new Settings());

    // Wrap everything inside the same transaction
    return dslContext.transactionResultAsync (configuration -> {

        /**
         *    Save the transaction configuration in the action context arguments so that
         * the action can pass down the same transaction into the services it depends on
         */
        ctx.args.put (Constants.DATABASE_TRANSACTION_KEY, configuration);

        // Make the call to the action itself
        return delegate.call (ctx);

    // Commit and release the connection when the action terminates
    }).thenComposeAsync (resultCompletionStage -> {

        return resultCompletionStage.thenApply (result -> {
            try {
                this.connection.commit();
                JDBCUtils.safeClose (this.connection);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DatabaseException (e);
            }
            return result;
        });

    // In case something wrong happens, rollback the transaction
    }).exceptionally (throwable -> {

        try {
            this.connection.rollback();                
            JDBCUtils.safeClose (this.connection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException (e);
        }
        throw new DatabaseException (throwable);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem of this approach is that I need to create a new class (very similar to jOOQ DAOImpl class) to use the configuration stored in the Http context:

```
public abstract class DAOImpl<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>, P, T> implements DAO<R, P, T> {

  ...
  @Override
  public /* non-final */ Configuration configuration() {

    if (Http.Context.current.get() != null)
        return (Configuration) Http.Context.current().args.get (Constants.DATABASE_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    return this.configuration;
  }
  ...
  @Override
  public /* non-final */ List<P> findAll() {
    return using(configuration())
            .selectFrom(table)
            .fetch()
            .map(mapper());
  }
  ... 
}
```

Other problem is that I need to set the configuration manually if I try to access to the database using a Dao when the Http context does not exist yet (in an *ActionCreator* for example).

I have read several links about it:

[jOOQ initializing DAO Best Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053345/jooq-initializing-dao-best-approach)

[jOOQ examples](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples)

But I'm not sure what is the best way to do the following:

1. Work with only one configuration due to I only has one database.
2. I would like to know if there is a better approach than I have developed, that is, without "overwrite" the DAOImpl class (taking into account that I would like to have only one instance of every Dao)

Comment: As far as the DAOs are concerned, there's clearly a missing feature, which I have registered just now: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5916. They should offer asynchronous methods as well. Other than that, I'm not so sure if I understand your question. What's a `delegate` for instance? And are you worrying about putting the configuration in some context, rather than passing it explicitly?

Comment: Hi Lukas, in Play you can add a custom behaviour to a web service (in a method of a controller instance really), in this case creating a database transaction to simulate the existing `@Transactional` in other frameworks like Spring. With `return delegate.call (ctx);` you tell to Play, "ok, continue the execution of the rest of the code" (although not exactly the same, it is similar to `return ctx.proceed();` in a JavaEE `@AroundInvoke` interceptor).

Comment: I'm trying to put the transaction configuration in the HTTP context to avoid have to "inject it" in the controller and pass it throught service layer and set in the DAO instances (using `setConfiguration` method of jOOQ DAOImpl class)

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the explanation. My "play" is a bit rusty. But I agree, that doesn't feel right. Unfortunately, I don't have a satisfactory answer right now...